# Problema ao compilar singleton c++

Tags: c++, singleton

Quando tó tentando compilar uma `singleton` eu obtenho sempre a seguinte mensagem de retorno:

> g++ -g -Wall `pkg-config --cflags stage`  -fPIC `pkg-config --libs stage`  -c -Wall Connection.cpp
>   cc   Connection.o   -o Connection
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: na função `_start':
>   (.text+0x20): referência indefinida para`main'
>   Connection.o: na função `Connection::Connection()':
>   /home/orion/Documentos/Workspace/AngoritmoTCC/Aplicacao-Tcc-Refazer/Connection.cpp:16: referência indefinida para`vtable for Connection'
>   Connection.o: na função `Connection::getInstance()':
>   /home/orion/Documentos/Workspace/AngoritmoTCC/Aplicacao-Tcc-Refazer/Connection.cpp:20: referência indefinida para`Connection::sinstance'
>   /home/orion/Documentos/Workspace/AngoritmoTCC/Aplicacao-Tcc-Refazer/Connection.cpp:21: referência indefinida para `operator new(unsigned long)'
>   /home/orion/Documentos/Workspace/AngoritmoTCC/Aplicacao-Tcc-Refazer/Connection.cpp:21: referência indefinida para`Connection::sinstance'
>   /home/orion/Documentos/Workspace/AngoritmoTCC/Aplicacao-Tcc-Refazer/Connection.cpp:22: referência indefinida para `Connection::sinstance'
>   /home/orion/Documentos/Workspace/AngoritmoTCC/Aplicacao-Tcc-Refazer/Connection.cpp:21: referência indefinida para`operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
>   Connection.o:(.data.DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0[DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0]+0x0): referência indefinida para `__gxx_personality_v0'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   : recipe for target 'Connection' failed
>   make: *** [Connection] Error 1

Desta forma, não consigo compilar, e preciso transformar em um arquivo .so, para rodar usando uma biblioteca. alguem pode me ajudar?

## Editado

### Arquivo Connection.cpp

```
Connection::Connection() {
}

static Connection *Connection::getInstance() {
    if (!Connection::sinstance)
        Connection::sinstance = new Connection();
    return Connection::sinstance;
}
```

### Arquivo Connection.h

```
#ifndef CONNECTION_H
#define CONNECTION_H

class Connection {
public:
    static Connection *getInstance();
    Connection();
    virtual ~Connection();


private:
    static Connection *sinstance;
};

#endif /* CONNECTION_H */
```

### Main.cpp

```
int main(){
    ControllerPrincipal *controller = new ControllerPrincipal();
}
```

### MaKeFIle

```
COMMON_DIR = ../common

run: all

all: coordination.so createScenario

createScenario: createScenario.cpp
    $(CXX) createScenario.cpp -o createScenario

coordination.so: ControllerPrincipal.o main.o Connection
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LINKFLAGS) main.o ControllerPrincipal.o 
Connection.o -o coordination.so -shared

ControllerPrincipal.o: ControllerPrincipal.cpp ControllerPrincipal.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LINKFLAGS) -c ControllerPrincipal.cpp

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LINKFLAGS) -c main.cpp

Connection.o: Connection.cpp Connection.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LINKFLAGS) -c -Wall Connection.cpp


clean:
    @rm -f *.o *.so  server createScenario

reset:
    rm -rf nRobos*
```

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente, você está tentando compilar um arquivo para se tornar um executável. Ele não está sendo compilado para biblioteca (nem estática nem dinâmica), usando um arquivo objeto como intermediário.

Analisando os comandos executados:

```
g++ Connection.cpp -c
```

Basicamente está sendo dito ao compilador `g++` para fazer a compilação parcial do arquivo `Connection.cpp`, resultando portanto no arquivo objeto `Connection.o`.

```
cc Connection.o -o Connection
```

`cc` normalmente é um apelido para o `gcc`. Quando usado passando arquivos objetos e nenhuma flag indicativa do alvo desejado da compilação, ele gera um único arquivo executável contendo todas as informações dos arquivos objetos passados como argumento. A saída normalmente é o arquivo `a.out`, porém ao usar `-o Connection`, você está direcionando a saída para `Connection`.

Para o `gcc` (e `g++`), o executável deve ter necessariamente uma função `main` descrita em algum dos arquivos objetos incluídos. A ausência dessa função causa um erro na hora de linkar o executável.

No seu caso, `Connection` parece ser uma classe a ser importada no projeto, não parece ser onde mora a função `main`. Ao usar o comando `cc Connection.o -o Connection`, você não estaria passando a função `main`, gerando o erro descrito anteriormente.

Como o código não foi postado, isso é o máximo que consigo deduzir com base nas informações passadas.

---

Também recomendo usar o `g++` para fazer a compilação final, de modo que a biblioteca padrão do C++ também seja incluída para o runtime

Comment: Posso passar o código caso queira, mas ele são simples, uma singleton a ser usado no player/stage para simulação robótica. Isto é, o código é apenas isto, um arquivo .o a ser reunido com outros de mesma extensão em um arquivo .so a ser passado ao player para servir de controller do sistema. se puder me ajudar com a solução, fico grato.

Não há nada de especial, realmente, é só a singleton mesmo, é para representar dentro da simulação a comunicação que teríamos através de ondas de radio.

Comment: Então não tem função `main`?

Comment: Tá neste repositorio
https://github.com/andersoney/AlgoritmoNovo.git

Comment: Não, é um extern "C". que é chamado pelo stage.

Comment: Desculpa, para compilar vc vai precisar instalar o stage pq precisa da biblioteca do mesmo. Posso disponibilizar o codigo, mas a instalação, não sei como ajudar pq varia de sistema a sistema.

Comment: Veja como fazer uma pergunta com um exemplo mínimo, verificável e completo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve; mínimo significa que vai ter aquilo que é necessário para reproduzir seu problema, verificável significa que outros vão conseguir verificar o que houve e completo significa que não tem dependência externa, está tudo no exemplo fornecido junto à pergunta.

Comment: para verificar é simples. COmenta o extern "C" e usa uma main no lugar.

Comment: Vou subir o exemplo assim.

Comment: @AndersoneyRodrigues , sua pergunta continua do mesmo jeito. Melhore-a com um mcve

Comment: Pronto. Coloquei exemplos

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi, o modo como o codigo fica é este.

```
static Connection& getInstance(int numbRobot) {
    static Connection instance(numbRobot); // Guaranteed to be destroyed.
    // Instantiated on first use.
    return instance;
}
```