# O que é aquele arquivo criado pelo nasm quando eu "compilo" ele?

Tags: assembly, debug, nasm

Eu compilei um código assembly no nasm usando "nasm.exe -f win64 programa.asm -o programa.o" e fiquei com mais duvidas do que tudo.

Meu intuito em fazer esse simples programa é de pegar um código puro, assembly, e fazê-lo executável e assim passar ele por um depurador como o Immunity dbg e se realmente o que programei é de fato "LITERAL" quando interage com a CPU.

Fiz isso e não deu para executar esse programa.o, pesquisei na internet e falou que preciso "linkar" - o que seria isso? - com o minGW e eu fiz isso. Mas só que fiquei com mais duvidas ainda, por que esse minGW ta no meio disso? Qual é o objetivo daquele arquivo obj?

Estou usando windows 10 e sou um curioso, apenas. Além de não achar quase nada em assembly para windows 10.

Desculpe se a pergunta for besta, mas eu não encontro explicações sobre isso mesmo em inglês, talvez eu faça outro post em inglês para abranger mais pessoas.

Comment: Aquele arquivo `.o` é um arquivo chamado de _arquivo objeto_. Ele está a um ponto de ser um executável, mas não o é. De cabeça, eu sei que eu e o [Maniero](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero) em respostas distintas já falamos sobre arquivos objeto e sobre link-edição, vale a pena cavar. Vou tentar procurar algo nas minhas respostas para ver se ajuda a esclarecer.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213804/64969 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/236010/64969

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/306915/64969

Comment: Nossa obrigado. Vou dar uma olhada melhor no que você sugeriu.